# texture packer doesn't create one huge image of images

Tags: libgdx, texturepacker

I'm following a book about libgdx and I haven't comprehend texture atlases as I would like to. As far as I understood, Texture Packer creates one huge image with all textures and atlas or pack file. But when I run it it creates atlas/pack file and than stores all the images one by one. I end up with the same number of images as I stared with, therefore I have done nothing. Why is that happening? What additional option needs to be checked, so I can create one huge file of images? I used this texture packer https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-texturepacker-gui/

Comment: What size are your source images, and can you post your configuration json file?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. The size of images was too big for my settings, and therefore it could only stuff one image in the atlas. Silly me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use the Texture Packer GUI as it is easier and faster to pack textures from source. If you work with eclipse, you can do the following.

1. Make `raw-assets` folder inside your `android/assets` folder and copy your images there
2. Make `pack` folder inside your `android/assets` folder
3. Create a new class on the Desktop project and copy this code

   ```java
   public class TextureSetup {

       static String input = "../android/assets/raw-assets";
       static String output = "../android/assets/pack/";
       static String atlas = "my-assets";

       public static void main(String[] args){
           TexturePacker.process(input, output, atlas);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Run as java app

If you use gradle and the TexturePacker class is not found, add **gdx-tools** to your `build.gradle` file.

```gradle
project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
    }
}
```

Refer to the official doc on Texture Packer for more info and options https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer

Comment: This is a nice approach. My original problem was the size of images I wanted to pack. They were to big for standard settings.